# Next JS 13: Missing script: "dev" on fresh Next JS 13 App

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, next.js

I've just started learning React with Next JS 13. When I tried to run `npm run dev` on clean Next app created by using `npx create-next-app@latest --experimental-app` I get an error:

```
npm ERR! Missing script: "dev"
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ekric\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-03-03T00_27_56_303Z-debug-0.log
```

It says `Missing script: "dev"` however in my `package.json` file I see:

```
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
```

Here's my full `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "additictive-social",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/node": "18.14.4",
    "@types/react": "18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "18.0.11",
    "next": "13.2.3",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.9.5"
  }
}
```

Where am I going wrong here? I'm using Next 13 with TypeScript React.

Comment: Are you in the right directory?

Comment: Simple fix! Thank's for pointing that out.